# Condense Query Results with Wildcard

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have the following query:

```
select programVersion, count(programVersion) 
     from records R 
     inner join Programs P 
         on P.programID=R.usageProgramID 
     where programName="word" 
     group by programVersion;
```

Results:

```
+----------------+-----------------------+
| programVersion | count(programVersion) |
+----------------+-----------------------+
| 12.0.0         |                     1 |
| 12.2.0         |                 32190 |
| 12.2.3         |                    20 |
| 12.2.6         |                  3990 |
| 12.2.8         |                 13128 |
| 12.3.1         |                   114 |
| 12.3.2         |                     4 |
| 12.3.4         |                    20 |
| 14.0.0         |                    57 |
| 14.1.0         |                 86587 |
| 14.1.3         |                    44 |
| 14.1.4         |                   728 |
| 14.2.0         |                    42 |
| 14.2.2         |                   130 |
| 14.2.3         |                 88219 |
| 14.2.5         |                    66 |
| 14.3.0         |                   126 |
| 14.3.1         |                    36 |
| 14.3.2         |                    74 |
+----------------+-----------------------+
```

For this purpose I don't really care about the minor version increments.  What I'm really interested in is the differences in major increments.  Is there a way that I can get the results combined past the first period?

Example Output

```
+----------------+-----------------------+
| programVersion | count(programVersion) |
+----------------+-----------------------+
| 12             |         total of 12's |
| 14             |         total of 14's |
+----------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: What exactly do you want as output?

Comment: @ypercube: Please see the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function to get the part before the first dot and then group:

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(programVersion, '.', 1) AS programMajorVersion, 
       count(programVersion) AS totalIncrements 
     from records R 
     inner join Programs P 
         on P.programID=R.usageProgramID 
     where programName="word" 
     group by SUBSTRING_INDEX(programVersion, '.', 1) 
     order by CAST(programMajorVersion AS unsigned) ;
```

The above may not be the most efficient on a large table. If you have indexes that your version uses and is efficient, you may use that as a derived table and then aggregate with the substring function:

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(programVersion, '.', 1) AS programMajorVersion, 
       SUM(cnt) AS totalIncrements 
     from  
     ( select programVersion, count(programVersion) AS cnt
         from records R 
         inner join Programs P 
             on P.programID=R.usageProgramID 
         where programName="word" 
         group by programVersion
     ) AS t
     group by SUBSTRING_INDEX(programVersion, '.', 1) 
     order by CAST(programMajorVersion AS unsigned) ;
```